# How to add New Row in datagridview which is bound to the datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview that is bound to a datasource. I have to add a new row in datagridview when I click Edit button or New button.I tried some code but its giving me error, code is given below

```
DataGridView grdview = new DataGridView();
grdview.Rows.Add();
grdview.Rows[grdview.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].Selected = true;
grdview.BeginEdit(false);
```

I also tried typecasting of datasource to datatable but no solution.

Answer (score 14):

It seems that you are using the `DataSource` property of the `DataGridView`. When this property is used to bind to data you cannot explicitly add rows directly to the DataGridView. *You must instead add rows directy to your data source*.

`If you are binding a List`

```
//Assume Student list is bound as Dtaasource
List<Student> student = new List<Student>();

//Add a new student object to the list
student .Add(new Student());

//Reset the Datasource
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.DataSource = student;
```

`If you are binding DataTable`

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

 DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();

// Add the row to the rows collection.
table.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

Answer (score 7):

No, if the `DataGridView` is data bound to some data source then you cannot add new rows/columns. You will have to create a new data set (`DataTable` or whatever) with the required columns and then re-bind the `DataGridView` to that.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Bind to a `BindingSource` instead and you will preserve NewRow