# Error with databound DataGridView Display Textbox's Text

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview (dgvSelectedItem)and I want it to display some values from textboxes but I have this error

```
Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound
```

My code is:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

string conn = "server=.;uid=sa;pwd=123;database=PharmacyDB;";

Okbtn()
{
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select UnitPrice from ProductDetails where prdctName like '"+txtSelectedName.Text + "'", conn);

da.Fill(dt);

dgvSelectedItem.DataSource = dt;

//this code work but when I add these lines the Error appear

dgvSelectedItem.Rows.Add(txtSelectedName.Text);
dgvSelectedItem.Rows.Add(txtSelectedQnty.Text); }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
Actually I did but Error still appearing

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915116/how-to-add-new-row-in-datagridview-which-is-bind-to-the-datasource Or maybe you really want to add a column? This is doable..

Comment: actually  ,It doesn't work

Comment: It might just be me, but I am not quite sure what you are asking here. You can't assign a `DataSource` and programmatically add rows.

Comment: So, if there another way to achieve my needs ,please 
I'll be so grateful

Comment: @user3423060: I have revised my answer for you in light of the new details. Let me know if it helps and if I can do anything to improve the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED Per OP Comment**

So you want a user to enter the product name and quantity, then to run a query against the database to retrieve the unit price information. Then you want to display all of that information to your user in a `DataGridView` control.

Here is what I suggest:

1. Include the `prdctName` field in your `SELECT` clause.
2. If you want to bind all relevant data to a `DataGridView` including the `Quantity` variable and your `TotalPrice` calculation, then include them in your `SELECT` statement. When you bind data to the control from an SQL query like this, the result set is mapped to the grid. In other words, if you want information to be displayed when setting the `DataSource` property then you need to include the information in your SQL result set.
3. Don't use `LIKE` to compare for `prdctName` as it slightly obscures the purpose of your query and instead just use the `=` operator.
4. In addition from a table design perspective, I would add a `UNIQUE INDEX` on the `prdctName` column if it is indeed unique in your table - which I sense it likely is. This will improve performance of queries like the one you are using.

Here is what your SQL should look like now:

```
SELECT prdctName, UnitPrice, @Quantity AS Quantity, 
       UnitPrice * @Quantity AS Total_Price 
FROM ProductDetails
WHERE prdctName = @prdctName
```

A few other suggestions would be to use prepared SQL statements and .NET's `using` statement as already noted by **Soner Gönül**. I'll try to give you motivation for applying these techniques.

***Why should I use prepared SQL statements?***

You gain security against [SQL Injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and a performance boost as prepared statements (aka parameterized queries) are compiled and optimized once.

***Why should I use the `using` statement in .NET?***

It ensures that the `Dispose()` method is called on the object in question. This will release the unmanaged resources consumed by the object.

I wrote a little test method exemplifying all of this:

```
private void BindData(string productName, int quantity)
{
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    string sql = "SELECT prdctName, UnitPrice, @Quantity AS Quantity, " + 
                        "UnitPrice * @Quantity AS Total_Price " + 
                 "FROM ProductDetails " + 
                 "WHERE prdctName = @prdctName";

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
         using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
         {
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prdctName", productName);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", quantity);
             using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
             {
                adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Here's a sample input and output of this method:

```
BindData("Lemon Bars", 3);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've used BindData method like this:BindData(txtSelectedName.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtSelectedQnty.Text));
but nothing happen ,no error ,no result instead of the UnitPrice

Comment: So just the `UnitPrice` column showed up? Is the `AutoGenerateColumns` property set to `false`?

Comment: Can you step through the code and see how many columns the `DataTable` object has after the call to `Fill`?

Comment: How ? I don't understand

Comment: If you're using VS here is a guide: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-A-Beginn

Comment: I ran the query via SQLFiddle and it shows that MS SQL Server 2012 should yield the anticipated result set. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ba632/1

Comment: Add this line after the `Fill` in order to make the debugging process easier for you. `MessageBox.Show(string.Join(", ", dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(dc => dc.ColumnName)));`

Comment: PrdctName,UnitPrice,Quantity,Total_Price
that what show up in the messagebox

Comment: This is really bizarre - but we will get this! Try setting `DataSource` to `dataTable.DefaultView` The other thing that I can suggest is to re-add the `DataGridView` control to the `Form`.

Comment: You did it thank you so much , but it display one row only for one item

Comment: dgvSelectedItem.Rows.Add(BindData(txtSelectedName.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtSelectedQnty.Text));
Doesn't work I'm starter learner so forgive me for my bad question

Comment: So which approach worked? `DefaultView` or the re-add of the control? The way that your query is written it will only display information for one product. You can omit the `WHERE` clause of the SQL query to get back information in regards to each product.

Comment: Re-add of the control and actually ,as well as writting DefaultView

Comment: I was using the wizard to add columns I removed them all and it works so no need to add new DataGridView :) , I'm just practice with new and old forms which I've added to test the code

Answer (score 0):

I searched over the internet and looks like there is no way to add new rows programmatically when you set your [`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of your `DataGridView`.

Most common way is to add your `DataTable` these values and then bind it to `DataSource` property like:

```
da.Fill(dt);
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["UnitPrice"] = txtSelectedName.Text;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
dgvSelectedItem.DataSource = dt;
```

Also `conn` is your *connection string*, not an `SqlConnection`. Passing `SqlConnection` as a second parameter in your `SqlDataAdapter` is a better approach in my opinion.

You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Finally, don't forget to use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlDataAdapter`.

I assume you want to use your text as `%txtSelectedName.Text%`, this is my example;

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=.;uid=sa;pwd=123;database=PharmacyDB;"))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select UnitPrice from ProductDetails where prdctName like @param"))
{
   cmd.Connection = conn;
   cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue("@param", "%" + txtSelectedName.Text + "%");
   using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, conn))
   {
       da.Fill(dt);
       DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
       dr["UnitPrice"] = txtSelectedName.Text;
       dt.Rows.Add(dr);
       dt.Rows.Add(dr);
       dgvSelectedItem.DataSource = dt;
   }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I just assumed that the OP was meaning to use `LIKE` without any wildcards. A query optimizer would likely just reduce that to a `=`.

Comment: I want the user to write the name and quantity of the product in the textboxes and I want it to be shown in the datagridview according to these data the price of the selected product will be appear from the database, I have tried all that solutions but it doesn't work, also I've tried to use an array to add rows to the datgridview but doesn't make sense too

Comment: @DerekW It is not totally clear what OP wants. That's why I use it between `% %`. But it can be change easily of course.

Comment: @SonerGönül: Yes, I didn't mean to say it as a critique. I was just commenting on how some ambiguity lead to different interpretations.